# Is there a way to send two messages with socket

Tags: python

Im trying to send a messages from the server to the client

I tried deleting the .close and puting a while loop on print but it still doesn't won't to work

**Client**

```
import socket 

s = socket.socket()            
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 12345  

s.connect((host, port))
while True:
    print (s.recv(1024))
```

**Server**

```
import socket               

s = socket.socket()  
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 12345     

s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(5)
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print ('Got connection from', addr)
    x = str(input("ënter a message"))

    data = x.encode()
    c.send(data)
```

I expect the output to be 2 messages from the server but it is only sending 1 and then closing the connection

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54053252/edit) your question to include your input/output: what messages do you try to send, what gets received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch your `accept` and `while True:` lines.  Once you accept a connection, keep sending on the same connection.

Note that TCP is a streaming protocol.  There is no concept of "messages", but just a bunch of bytes.  If you send fast enough, such as:

```
c.send(b'abc')
c.send(b'def')
```

then `recv(1024)` could receive `b'abcdef'`.  For more complex communication, you'll have to define a protocol and buffer `recv` until you are sure you have a complete message.  A simple way in this case is read until you find a newline, or send a byte (or more) indicating the size of the total message before sending the actual message.